# $root scope with same variable with different values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

First of all excuse me if this doesn't make any sense.

I have a root-scope with two different values assigned in the same controller,and now i want to print those two values using that root-scope.....how can i achieve this

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $rootScope.name = 'hello';
  $rootScope.name="world";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

  
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
   
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

from the above i want to print hello world......

Comment: As a side note, you should prefer `$scope` here. Avoid using `$rootScope` when it is not necessary.

Comment: @mistails even if you use $scope you will get only "world"

Comment: This comment was not intended to **answer** the question but to **warn you** about the use of `$rootScope`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the first value when you call $rootScope.name = "world";, I recommend you make an object instead like so;

```
$rootScope.helloWorld = {hello: "hello", world: "world"};
```

In the html;

```
<p>{{helloWord.hello}} {{helloWorld.world}}</p>
```

Comment: Won't work. Should be `<p>{{$rootScope.helloWord.hello}} {{$rootScope.helloWorld.world}}</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is

```
$rootScope.name = "hello";
$rootScope.name += " world";
```

In your code, you are just replacing the value.

Comment: may be your correct....surely its like replacing i missed that but lets see do we have any other choices

Comment: Well, it's either this solution (which still doesn't make any sense, or just do  $rootScope.hello = "hello"; $rootScope.world = "world"; and display them in the view with {{hello}}{{world}}

Comment: i know that way but a bloody interviewer makes me blank and i am hunting this now